# Does the non-serotonin-like half of LSD resemble anything of significance?

Tags: molecular-structure

LSD's resemblance to serotonin explains many of its effects on the brain, but I noticed only half of it resembles serotonin. The question I have, is does the other half resemble anything, particularly anything of significance?

In this image the bottom half resembles serotonin:
[image: Serotonin-like half of LSD]

In this image, the other half is shown, and I wonder if there's anything that it resembles.
[image]

[Image by By Ben Mills - Own work, Public Domain, [https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=14584151]](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=14584151)

Comment: I don't see how the first structure is supposed to resemble [serotonin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serotonin). Anyway, as for the second fragment, it appears to be *N*,*N*-diethyl-2-methylpropanamide, CAS 33931-44-1.